# Debugging error message: "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly"

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer

One of my users is intermittently getting a dialog in IE 8 that says:

A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly

This problem has been reported numerous times in the MSDN forums and other places on the web.  For example:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0fdb7550-0a59-4553-a90e-1958475f2ce5/how-to-debug-a-script-on-this-page-is-causing-internet-explorer-to-run-slowly?forum=iewebdevelopment
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/dafffdd8-a390-4a3c-a904-867acaec298e/error-message-a-script-on-this-page-is-causing-internet-explorer-to-run-slowly-for-ie8?forum=whatforum
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e9d16d2a-60e1-4d6f-8f80-0d981eab3a2e/a-script-on-this-page-is-causing-your-web-browser-to-run-slowly?forum=bingmapsajax

So, this question is a duplicate of those and many others.  But it is an intentional duplicate, because I don't think any of those questions were answered in a way that helps a user (developer) to determine precisely what in his scenario causes the dialog to appear.

I know that based on this page:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500

the dialog appears when a certain number of statements have executed since a new script begins execution (through a variety of means).  By default the number of statements is 5,000,000 but this is configurable via a registry entry.

The general prescription to this problem is a combination of:

- Write less code.  Unfortunately, this is not always possible.
- Use web workers. This is not an option for IE before IE 10, nor with
  some mobile browsers.
- Use setTimeOut, setInterval, event handlers, etc to break the
  script(s) up.  This is a legitimate strategy across all browsers.

So, I understand what the problem is in general terms, and I understand what the options are to solve the problem, again in general terms.  The question is, how to determine what area(s) of the code are causing the dialog to appear for a specific user?  Often this problem occurs with a very large code base (including third party libraries), so a manual review of the code base without some tooling support is not feasible.

Most browsers, including IE8 and later, have profiling tools that enable the developer to determine JavaScript CPU usage.  With the exception of IE, other browsers decide a script is long running not based on the numbers of statements executed but rather the amount of time the script spent executing.  To this end, the profilers available in (or as add ons) to the browsers can identify the percentage and usually raw time spent executing a function, both inclusively and exclusively for a function, and the results can be sorted accordingly.  IE's profiler will also give you a count of how often a function is called.  None of these profilers tell you how many statements of code within a function were executed during profiling; they tell you only how long was spent in the function and how many times the function was called.  This doesn't help with IE's slow script dialog logic, which is based on the number of statements (not time) that were executed.  There is sometimes a correlation between the time spent executing a function and the number of statements, but it is not a reliable relationship as of course different types of statements  can take very different lengths of times to execute (e.g. many native JavaScript functions are faster than calls which update the DOM; both have the same statement count but the former executes faster than the latter, making examining %/raw time not very useful).

One approach I've used that is of some value is when the slow script dialog appears, start the debugger in IE (if not already started) and select the break on next statement command in the debugger.  Then click the dialog button in the browser that allows the slow script to continue executing.  At this point, the debugger is invoked and the developer can examine the call stack to determine what is executing at the time the slow script dialog appears.  This is okay, but a very manual approach and there's no guarantee there aren't multiple scripts running that can at different times invoke the dialog.

An interesting idea I've seen suggested is to use a JavaScript code coverage tool to instrument the code base.  There are multiple JavaScript code coverage options out there, but the ease of use of a browser extension that could dynamically instrument the code seems like an ideal solution.  (Another interesting idea is to use a proxy server, for example http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/manual.html; 'jscoverage --server --proxy', but I couldn't get this to work on virtually any website, except the the silicon forks website itself).  There's a proof of concept one available for Chrome (http://googletesting.blogspot.ca/2011/10/scriptcover-makes-javascript-coverage.html) that I think could be a great start for helping resolve the the slow script problem -- if such an extension could be made for IE.

So, to reiterate my main question is what tools/processes can one use to debug/analyze a slow script dialog appearing on a user's machine?  A subquestion would be, does anyone know of any JavaScript code analysis tools that could be repurposed to help in diagnosing the slow script dialog in IE, and that takes minimal deployment effort? Can an IE extension be written, in theory, that does the sort of code coverage as the Google' script cover extension does?

Thank you,

Notre

Comment: UM, nobody has time to read all that. And after reading it all, you are basically asking for a tool and those questions normally get closed.

Comment: I appreciate it's long but I hope someone will take the time.  I tried to describe what research I've already done.

Comment: Hi @Notre have you checked any JS profilers? Looks like firebug and chrome developer tools are good for start. This article may help: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/ and also this : https://getfirebug.com/javascript

Comment: Hi @artuc. Yes, I did.  The problem is that these profilers will report the amount of time used in a function, but not how many statements are executed.  It is the number of statements that IE cares about not time (in contrast with other browsers that look at time).  I am a big fan of these profilers though, in general.

Answer (score 0):

In the old times JavaScript was not used that much. Pages used to me more static. These days the PC's were less powered and it was more popular to run complex tasks on the server.  JavaScript was only used for some animations.

Microsoft (my way or no way) took their time to acknowledge heavily JavaScript-ed content. (They were also fiddling with their JScript in IE8). Until IE9 they were considering that running > 5 000 000 instruction in a script is a potential mistake.

I'm not aware of any tool that retrieves the instructions count. It's a browser build in feature.

But most of the browsers retrieve the execution time of a function. I know that in every different computer, same number of instructions can take different times, but you can set a benchmark.

Run a script with 5 000 000 instructions on the machine and see how long it takes to run. Then use that time to benchmark your other JavaScript. It's not 100 % accurate but it can became close once you fiddle with it.

Since old IE developer tools are quite poor you can use some third party one. A ussage example here:
[deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer](http://ejohn.org/blog/deep-tracing-of-internet-explorer/)

Anyway, the  “A script on this page is causing your computer to run slow ...” is only a problem in **IE4 - IE8**. Since those browsers **are obsolete**, so should this question be.

Comment: Unfortunately, IE 8 is not obsolete.  Win XP is obsolete, but MS is supporting IE 8 until Windows 7 reaches end of life, which will be quite some time.  It also has pretty significant market share, particularly in corporate environments.  And IE 8 brings up that dialog in response to number of statements executed, not time like other browser :(

Comment: I'm trying to say that at least development for IE8 should somehow be obsolete. I will encourage the user to update and developers to worry less about it, but the big corporations hold this back!

Comment: I totally agree - it should be obsolete.  Some day, it will be, but until that day, it's frustrating :(